# numeric up down control in vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, numericupdown

Is there an in-built numeric updown control in vba or do we need to create a control like that?

If there is such a control then what are the events that we may use.

Pls suggest.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the `SpinButton1` control for that

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

**CODE**

You can either set the min and max of the `SpinButton1` in design time or at runtime as shown below.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    SpinButton1.Min = 0
    SpinButton1.Max = 100
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
    TextBox1.Text = SpinButton1.Value
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

If you want to increase or decrease the value of the textbox based on what user has input in the textbox then use this. This also makes the textbox a "Number Only" textbox which just fulfills your other request ;)

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinDown()
    TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) - 1
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()
    TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + 1
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Select Case KeyAscii
      Case vbKey0 To vbKey9, 8
      Case Else
        KeyAscii = 0
        Beep
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Made my day.....In fact i linked two spin buttons with text boxes to achieve more means..... Is there a way to allow only numbers in a text box that has a spin control button linked with it....????

Comment: Set the `.Locked` property of the Textbox to `TRUE` so that no user can manually type into it. Rest the spin buttons will take care of it :)

Comment: Thanks Sid for all the help...that .locked things works fine.I'm allowing my users to manually enter the data...Though I have successfully restricted the entry of anything other than integers. ..but when I m entering the integers manually and then trying to increase/decrease it is not working fine. Say the value was 14 and now i manually change it to 5 and on click of increase it is becoming 15 instead of 6. Any ideas how to read this??

Comment: Yes that is because it is taking the value of the spinner. Updating the post to incorporate your new request... 2 mins

Comment: thanks man!!! may u pls suggest a better way to learn excel..i m trying by myself and using SO as one of the helping platforms..

Comment: From a beginner's point of view I would recommend these `FREE` ways. `MSDN` + `Forums like SO` + `Google` :) When you have time, try and visit old questions and see how people have solved various problems. They are really a good way to learn :) If you want to buy a book, you might want to try a book by John Walkenbach. http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/books/